# ASP.NET MVC 5 refactorizar metodo para consumir api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, api

me encuentro en una encrucijada, dado que estoy desarrollando una app web donde debo consumir una api por GET y POST, la logica del servicio la tengo resuelta, pero me gustaria refactorizar el codigo para no tener que estar repitiendo las mismas piezas en cada solicitud.

Tengo algo como lo siguiente:

Controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.0.1:1000/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("token");

            // GET Method
            HttpResponseMessage HttpResponseMessage = await client.GetAsync("api/url");

            MiModelo model = new MiModelo();
            if (HttpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var EmpResponse = HttpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<model >(EmpResponse);
            }

            return View(model );
        }
    }
```

a lo que quiero llegar es a algo como esto -> https://tahirnaushad.com/2017/09/04/consuming-asp-net-core-2-0-web-api-using-httpclient/ pero no eh podido, seria genial si alguien sabe, para que comparta sus conocimientos y ojalas le pueda servir a alguien mas.

Comment: ¿Cuales son esas piezas?

Comment: La llamada a la instancia de HttpClient que se hace en el using (var client = new HttpClient())

Las propiedades de la instancia. client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.0.1:1000/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("token");

El if

El return

Comment: No es mejor crear una función entonces? Mira la respuesta que te dejaron abajo :)

Comment: también podrías usar un ActionFilter para mantener los headers :D

Comment: Estoy tratando de hacer lo que aparece en este link https://tahirnaushad.com/2017/09/04/consuming-asp-net-core-2-0-web-api-using-httpclient/ para poder llamar de una forma facil a cada metodo get o post para hacer el request hacia la api.

Comment: Seria genial una ayuda para lograr dejar asi de simple la llamada a los metodos para hacer el request hacia la api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un refactor simple se puede hacer de esta manera:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var objhttp = new HttpClientHelper();

    using (var client = objhttp.GenerateClient())
    {
        // GET Method
        HttpResponseMessage HttpResponseMessage = await client.GetAsync("api/url");

        MiModelo model = new MiModelo();
        if (HttpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var EmpResponse = HttpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<model>(EmpResponse);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Crear una clase Helper, si lo prefiere puede ser static

```
public class HttpClientHelper
{
    public HttpClient GenerateClient()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.0.1:1000/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("token");
        return client;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, 2 consultas ante tu respuesta:

1.- De ser static tendría problemas al momento de manejar los token dentro del ciclo de vida o mas bien de la instancia de la aplicación?ya que ese token iria cambiando por cada usuario que se logeo.

2.- Para refactorizar el // Get Method, el if y el return se puede hacer algo?

Ya que estaba leyendo por ahí y encontré esto https://tahirnaushad.com/2017/09/04/consuming-asp-net-core-2-0-web-api-using-httpclient/ no se si se podrá realizar algo similar.

Comment: Hola, finalmente ocupe el helper pero habrá otra forma de solo instanciar el servicio una única vez?